# Can a Bard inspire another character’s inspiration roll?

Tags: dnd-5e, bard, stacking, inspiration

I was recently thinking of cool ideas for my new character, when I thought of something. Is it possible for another bard to inspire my inspiration roll? Or is it possible to inspire the roll of another bard’s inspiration? I don't think it would be overly game-breaking.

Example: A fighter makes a check, which he rolls bad for. The fighter uses an Inspiration die, then realizes that he will still probably not succeed. Another bard in the party gives him inspiration, which he uses immediately.

Comment: @Punintended [please don’t answer in comments](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/q/6533/14878).

Comment: @Punintended The point of a hold/close is to prevent answers. [Please don’t (mis)use comments to try to answer anyway.](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/q/6533/321) It’ll be reopened soon since it’s been clarified what game it’s about.

Comment: *"Another bard in the party gives him inspiration"* — do you mean *Bardic Inspiration* as an additional d6 or the *Inspiration* mechanics as the advantage to the roll?

Comment: What do you mean by "inspire a roll"? Bards do not inspire rolls in 5e. You either have Bardic Inspiration die, which you use on a particular roll you choose, or you have an Inspiration, which you use to get an Advantage.

Answer (score 5):

## No, for a myriad of reasons

### Game features of the same name don't stack

The [DMG Errata](http://media.wizards.com/2016/downloads/DND/DMG-Errata.pdf) covers what happens when two features with the same name are used.

> **Combining Game Effects (p. 252)**. This is a new subsection at
>   the end of the “Combat” section:
>
> Different game features can affect a target at the same time.
>   But when two or more game features have the same name,
>   only the effects of one of them—the most potent one—apply
>   while the durations of the effects overlap. For example, if
>   a target is ignited by a fire elemental’s Fire Form trait, the
>   ongoing fire damage doesn’t increase if the burning target is
>   subjected to that trait again. Game features include spells,
>   class features, feats, racial traits, monster abilities, and magic
>   items. See the related rule in the “Combining Magical Effects”
>   section of chapter 10 in the *Player’s Handbook*.

### There was never an opportunity for the 2nd bard

Bardic Inspiration dice are handed out during the Bard's turn as a Bonus Action. There is no option for a bard to hand one out off-turn. The scenario presented just isn't possible.

### You can have only one at a time.

The rules for doling at [Bardic Inspiration](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/basic-rules/classes#BardicInspiration) are clear:

> A creature can have only one Bardic Inspiration die at a time.
>   While your scenario doesn't have the fighter having more than one simultaneously, I wanted to cover this potential 'work around' of your scenario not working because of the opportunity failure detailed above.